# javascript arrays inside an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

the issue is .: in the following code ... when i call the method "addtocart" ...
it prints correctly when the array has only one element ....
but if it has more than 1 element it givs error as shown in the pic:
(Ignore the first "404" error)

[image]

```
 var counter=0;
function addToCart(productName,productImageURL,productPrice)
{
alert("in addTOCART() method");
var cartArray=new Array();
cartArray[counter]=doTask(productName, productImageURL, productPrice);
//cartArray.concat(doTask(productName, productImageURL, productPrice));
/*cartArray.push(doTask(productName, productImageURL, productPrice));*/
alert("came back to original method");
alert(cartArray.length);
for ( var i = 0; i < cartArray.length; i++) {
    var array_element = cartArray[i];
    console.log(array_element.toString());
}
alert(cartArray.toString());
counter++;

}


function doTask(productName,productImageURL,productPrice)
{
alert("inside java script");
var cartItem = new Array();
itemName=productName;
itemPrice=productPrice;
alert(itemPrice);
itemImageURL=productImageURL;
quantity=prompt("Please enter the quantity","1");
quantity=parseInt(quantity);
alert(quantity+2);

if (!isNaN( quantity ))
{
    alert("yes its a number");
    alert(itemImageURL);
    alert(itemPrice);
    alert(quantity);
    alert(itemName);
    alert(itemImageURL);
    totalAmount=itemPrice*quantity;
    alert(totalAmount);
    cartItem.push(itemImageURL,itemName,itemPrice,quantity,totalAmount);
    //alert(cartItem.toString());
    console.log(cartItem.toString());
    return cartItem;
}
```

Comment: All things aside, the indentations hurt my eyes. :(

Comment: as far as i know a array does have a `.toString()` method.

Comment: Avoid to name your iteration variable "int". That's a reserved keyword. Use "i" instead. Let me know :)

Comment: @roland ~ that's a valid answer if you ask me. Maybe not what causes his problem, but a valid addition nonetheless.

Comment: @roland.. ok i got it... but still its not working ... actually the int is automatically written by eclips IDE

Comment: Why are you doing `cartItem.push(itemImageURL,itemName,itemPrice,quantity,totalAmount);`?

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight yes right but i guess its not taking the inner array as an array ....instead its taking it as an object..
as the error in console shows..

Comment: @MayurGupta ~ your error doesn't have anything to do with something being an object or an array; both have `.toString()`. Your error means that you're trying to call `.toString()` on an `undefined`, which can happen if, for example, you're trying to access an element of an array that doesn't exist. (e.g. `cartArray[2]` when there are only 2 elements.)

Comment: @MayurGupta yep oyu may want to try `for (var i; i < cartArray.length; i++){alert(cartArray[i].toString());}` or something like that

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight never do a `for..in` against an array in Javascript.

Comment: @RichardNeilIlagan but `cartArray` IS defined

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight ~ yeah, but its elements **might not be**.

Comment: How do you make the array `more than 1 element`, call `addToCart()` twice?

Comment: @srain... ok i will explain it... actually i have a list of different products ... and on click of each product i am calling this method..
So when i click it the next time it contains more than 1 element.

Comment: Why are you doing "console.log(cartItem.toString)"? Why not try console.log(cartItem)?

Comment: That'l' give you better insight into what's happening.

Comment: create a jsfiddle and reproduce the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you make the array `more than 1 element` by calling `addToCart()` more than once.

The `counter` will `+1` after call `addToCart()`. The second time you call `addToCart()`, the `counter` is 1:

```
 // counter = 1;
 cartArray[counter]=doTask(productName, productImageURL, productPrice);
 // add log to trace cartArray
 console.log(cartArray);
```

the `cartArray` has 2 elements. index 0 is `undefined`;

**How to fix**

define `cartArray` out of `addToCart()`:

```
var counter=0;
var cartArray=new Array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your doTask function when quantity is null,you dont return anything.so cartArray contains a undefined element.try this:

```
function doTask(productName,productImageURL,productPrice)
{
alert("inside java script");
var cartItem = new Array();
itemName=productName;
itemPrice=productPrice;
alert(itemPrice);
itemImageURL=productImageURL;
quantity=prompt("Please enter the quantity","1");
quantity=parseInt(quantity);
alert(quantity+2);

if (!isNaN( quantity ))
{
    alert("yes its a number");
    alert(itemImageURL);
    alert(itemPrice);
    alert(quantity);
    alert(itemName);
    alert(itemImageURL);
    totalAmount=itemPrice*quantity;
    alert(totalAmount);
    cartItem.push(itemImageURL,itemName,itemPrice,quantity,totalAmount);
    //alert(cartItem.toString());
    console.log(cartItem.toString());
}
return cartItem 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that the error tells is that array_element is undefined.. which in turn means cartArray[int] is undefined.

Hence the problem can either be with you using int as a variable name.. or actually the cartArray element is actually undefined.

You can solve your problem by adding null checks (check for undefined) on cartArray before the for loop beings and within the for loop on cartArrray[int]